Chrome Extension + react , passing values from tab scope to extension scope
Simply put:
I need to know the websiteId in my outside (extension) scope.
So, where i have alert(websiteId) i would ideally run setWebsiteId(websiteId) but i know this is not possible as i cannot pass functions as args to the func of executeScript.
export const ExtensionPopup = ({ tab }) => {
 const [websiteId, setWebsiteId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      args: [],
      func: () => {
        const script = document.getElementById('pertentoScript');
        const url = new URL(script.src);
        const websiteId = url.searchParams.get('website-id');
        alert(websiteId);
      },
    });
  }, []);
  
  return <div></div>
}

I'm new to Chrome extensions, and can't find the proper documentation for this.

Replace alert(websiteId) with return websiteId and use the result of executeScript's Promise, see these examples.
